# IN and ON: Confused as to what is the logic here?

Tags: prepositions, in-on

Why is the preposition **in** used for ‘the mountains’ but **on** for ‘the beach’?

> 1. They wish to live IN the mountains or ON the beach.
> 2. Go IN the air ON the Plane.
>    Go IN the Car ON the Road.

Why is it ‘***in*** the air’ and ‘***in*** a car’, but ***on*** when we talk about a plane and a road?

Comment: You live *in* the mountains because you are surrounded by them; you would live *on* a singular mountain, since you would not be surrounded by it - the same goes for the beach. I would say that you can be *on* or *in* a plane, but *on* doesn't make much logical sense: it may simply be one of those quirks of idiom.

Comment: I got it.     On the plane      =>       I can stand       In the car  => Can only sit

Comment: Also see the tags [tag:in-on] and [tag:at-on].

Comment: This Q may better be asked on [ell.se]

Comment: related: [Do you live *on* a farm?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238713/do-you-live-on-a-farm) and [I grew up IN the east coast vs ON the east coast](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186423/i-grew-up-in-the-east-coast-vs-on-the-east-coast)

Comment: I think that most people would say "on a plane", and this does seem inconsistent with your logic (which i agree with).  It seems to be (guessing here) to do with *public transport*.  People would say they were "in a car" but "on a bus", "on a train", or "on a boat".  Similarly we say that we "got in/into a car" but "got onto/on a bus/train/plane".  It's hard to see any logic, i suppose it's just an evolved custom.  It just occurred to me that it might be to do with how we **get** into/onto the vehicle:  if we can walk onto it it's "on" and if we have to crouch or sit to get into it it's "in"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use "in" or "on"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-in-or-on) and others such as '“on the train” or “in the train”?'.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is advisable to use **IN when you are indicating a position for spaces with limitations** while it is relatively specific and does not denote anything enclosed.

   - *I'm in the office.*
2. Alternatively, **ON is used to denote a position for surfaces or a position just above or outside an area.**

   - *I'm in the office seated on a chair.*
3. **IN is used to denote a location of something inside space** while **ON generally denotes something above a surface or within proximity.**
4. **ON is used when you do not enclose something such as time**

   - *My retirement is effective on December 31st*

Comment: ... On the train? bus? **car?!**